# +CME ERROR: invalid paremeter

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gsm, pyserial, at-command

I'm trying to send SMS from my RaspberryPi using my own script in python. I'm using serial port on GPIO on the RPi to communicate with GSM modem. I have selected TEXT MODE sms format, listed smses, etc and it all works fine until it comes to sending a sms. When I want to send it I get error like in the tittle.

To quit sending a message I press esc button, press enter (to send it via serial) and it works great (modem sends back 'OK')
I know that to send a message, after the message content I have to send ctrl-z. Ofc in linux when i press ctrl-z i stop the program so it's impossible to press those keys and then enter. Thats why i made a function to send sms where i put ctrl-z char/sign.

When i run the program modem responds with an error like in the tittle(+CME ERROR: invalid paremeter or if you'd like the error code: +CME ERROR: 3518) I know this may seem stupid but I've been looking for an answer for two days and I've tried chr(26).encode(), "\x1a", "\x1A" (don't even know if there's a difference), I've tried to send it with a message content, separatly but nothing works

I may do something wrong but I have no idea what. So I post some code and datasheet screen how to send a message.
Sending a sms:

```
def sendSMS(self, phoneNumber=111111111, smsContent=""):
    # if phoneNumber==0:
    if phoneNumber!=111111111:
        print("Type phone number in: (without prefix +48): ", end="")
        phoneNumber = input()
        try:
            phoneNumber = int(phoneNumber)
        except Exception:
            print("Type in an integer")
            time.sleep(1)
            self.sendSMS()
    print("Type text message content (press ENTER to send): ")
    smsContent = str(input())
    char_CtrlZ = "\x1a"
    quote = "\""
    command = "AT+CMGS=" + quote + str(phoneNumber) + quote + "," + quote + "129" + quote
    message = smsContent + char_CtrlZ
    self.serialConnection.send(command)
    time.sleep(1)
    self.serialConnection.receive()
    time.sleep(1)
    if self.checkModemResponse()==True: #here I send empty string (few times, if needed) until modem responses with '>'
        print("No '>' in modem response")
        print("Message did not send")
    else:
        self.serialConnection.send(message, True, False)
        time.sleep(2)
        self.serialConnection.receive(True, True, True)
        time.sleep(1)
        if self.serialConnection.responseState=="COMPLETE_OK":
            print("Your message has been sent!")    

def checkModemResponse(self, attempt=3):
    #I have 5 states of response: UNKNOWN; COMPLETE_OK - modem responses with OK; COMPLETE_ERROR - modem responses with ERROR; UNCOMPLETE - modem responses correctly but without ERROR or OK; EMPTY modem responds correctly but with empty string
    isUncomplete = True
    if self.serialConnection.responseState!="UNCOMPLETE":
        isUncomplete = False
        attempt -= 1
        if attempt > 0:
            print("Trying again..")
            someString = "attempt: " + str(attempt)
            self.serialConnection.send(someString)
            time.sleep(1)
            self.serialConnection.receive(True, True, True)
            time.sleep(1)
            if self.serialConnection.responseState!="UNCOMPLETE":
                self.checkModemResponse(attempt)
    return isUncomplete
```

And sending a command over serial:

```
def send(self, messageToSend, printWhatIsSent=True, addCR=True):
    if addCR==False:
        command = messageToSend
    else:
        command = messageToSend + "\r"
    if self.serialState==self.SERIAL_STATE[IDLE] and self.serialConnection.isOpen():
        self.responseState = self.RESPONSE_STATE[UNKNOWN]
        self.serialState = self.SERIAL_STATE[SENDING]
        commandToSendInBytes = self.str2byte(command)
        self.serialConnection.write(commandToSendInBytes)
        self.serialState = self.SERIAL_STATE[IDLE]
        if printWhatIsSent==True:
            print(">>>>> command sent: " + messageToSend)
    else:
        print("!!!ERROR: COMMAND DID NOT SEND!!!")
    self.serialConnection.flushOutput()
```

[How to send an SMS: +CMGS datesheet screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICQab.jpg)